# Logic issue in SQL Server function to handle search form submission and return table value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, search

I built a search form in a java web application as shown in the image below

[image: My Search Page]

Now a user of this page is expected to enter values into one or many of the 6 search fields or may do an open search leaving all fields blank.

I have the below function fetching results.

```
USE [KingsBayY]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[test_fn_transaction_search]
   (@receiptnum varchar(4001) ='',--00040401010000021
    @account varchar(4001) ='',
    @FN varchar(4001) ='',
    @ln varchar(4001) ='',--DateTime = '',
    @dt varchar(4001) ='',
    @program varchar(4001) ='',--)
    @attendee varchar(4001) =''
)
    --stdt
    --enddt
RETURNS @resulttable TABLE
   (trid  int,
    trdate   varchar(4001), --COLLATE database_default
    tramount       money,
    trinvoice  varchar(4001),
    trcashierid varchar(4001),
    trvoided varchar(4001),
    trrecallid varchar(4001),
    trrecalltype varchar(4001),
    trattendee varchar(4001),
    trperiod varchar(4001),
    stopbilling varchar(4001),
    caccount varchar(4001),
    firstname varchar(4001),
    lastname varchar(4001),
    trprogram varchar(4001),
    itemlookupcode varchar(4001),
    paydate varchar(4001)
    )
AS
BEGIN
IF (@receiptnum='' and @account='' and @FN=''and @ln='' and @dt='' and @program='' and @attendee='')
    INSERT INTO @resulttable
    select tr.ID AS [Transaction ID], tr.Time AS [trDt], tr.Total AS [amount], 
            tr.ReceiptNumber AS [invoice], tr.CashierID AS [cashid], 
            tr.Voided AS [voided], tr.RecallID AS [recallid], tr.RecallType AS [recalltype], 
            tr.Comment AS [attendee], tr.ReferenceNumber AS [trperiod], tr.StopBilling  AS [stopbilling],
            --fields from customer
            c.AccountNumber AS [accountnum], c.FirstName AS [firstname], c.LastName AS [lastname],
            --fields from item
            it.Description AS [programname], it.ItemLookupCode AS [trItemLookupCode],
            --fields from tenderentry
            tent.PaymentDate AS [paydate]

     from "Transaction" tr, TransactionEntry trent, Item it, Customer c, TenderEntry tent
     where trent.TransactionID = tr.ID
     and tent.TransactionID = tr.ID
     and trent.ItemID = it.ID
     and c.ID=tr.CustomerID
     and tr.RecallID =0 --parent
     --and tr.RecallType=0 --parent transactions and independant sales

     order by tr.id, tr.time;
else IF (@receiptnum<>'' or @account<>'' or @FN<>'' or @ln<>'' or @dt<>'' or @program<>'' or @attendee<>'')
    INSERT INTO @resulttable
    select tr.ID AS [Transaction ID], tr.Time AS [trDt], tr.Total AS [amount], 
            tr.ReceiptNumber AS [invoice], tr.CashierID AS [cashid], 
            tr.Voided AS [voided], tr.RecallID AS [recallid], tr.RecallType AS [recalltype], 
            tr.Comment AS [attendee], tr.ReferenceNumber AS [trperiod], tr.StopBilling  AS [stopbilling],
            --fields from customer
            c.AccountNumber AS [accountnum], c.FirstName AS [firstname], c.LastName AS [lastname],
            --fields from item
            it.Description AS [programname], it.ItemLookupCode AS [trItemLookupCode],
            --fields from tenderentry
            tent.PaymentDate AS [paydate]

     from "Transaction" tr, TransactionEntry trent, Item it, Customer c, TenderEntry tent
     where trent.TransactionID = tr.ID
     and tent.TransactionID = tr.ID
     and trent.ItemID = it.ID
     and c.ID=tr.CustomerID
     and tr.RecallID =0 --parent transactions and independant sales
     --and tr.RecallType=0 --
     and(
     tr.ReceiptNumber=ISNULL(@receiptnum,tr.ReceiptNumber)--invoice
     or c.accountnumber=ISNULL(@account,c.accountnumber)--account
     or c.FirstName=ISNULL(@FN, c.FirstName)
     or c.LastName=ISNULL(@ln, c.LastName)--customer
     or tr.time=ISNULL(@dt,tr.time)--date
     or tr.Comment=ISNULL(@attendee,tr.Comment)
     --program
     )
     union
     select tr.ID AS [Transaction ID], tr.Time AS [trDt], tr.Total AS [amount], 
            tr.ReceiptNumber AS [invoice], tr.CashierID AS [cashid], 
            tr.Voided AS [voided], tr.RecallID AS [recallid], tr.RecallType AS [recalltype], 
            tr.Comment AS [attendee], tr.ReferenceNumber AS [trperiod], tr.StopBilling  AS [stopbilling],
            --fields from customer
            c.AccountNumber AS [accountnum], c.FirstName AS [firstname], c.LastName AS [lastname],
            --fields from item
            it.Description AS [programname], it.ItemLookupCode AS [trItemLookupCode],
            --fields from tenderentry
            tent.PaymentDate AS [paydate]

     from "Transaction" tr, TransactionEntry trent, Item it, Customer c, TenderEntry tent
     where trent.TransactionID = tr.ID
     and tent.TransactionID = tr.ID
     and trent.ItemID = it.ID
     and c.ID=tr.CustomerID
     and tr.RecallID =0 --parent transactions and independant sales
     --and tr.RecallType=0 --
     and(
     ISNULL(tr.ReceiptNumber,'1')= ISNULL(@receiptnum,'1')--invoice
     and ISNULL(c.accountnumber,'1')= ISNULL(@account,'1')--account
     and ISNULL(c.FirstName,'1')= ISNULL(@FN,'1')
     and ISNULL(c.LastName,'1')= ISNULL(@ln,'1')--customer
     and ISNULL(tr.time,'1')= ISNULL(@dt,'1')--date
     and ISNULL(tr.Comment,'1')=ISNULL(@attendee,tr.Comment)
     --program
     )
     order by tr.id, tr.time;
RETURN
END
```

I am getting wrong results from this procedure. The problems I notice are,

1. no matter how try to search for.. open search, with one search parameter specified.. with multiple search parameter values specified, the procedure returns all results. How can I edit it to return only results according to the search parameters used?
2. some of the search parameters may not be an exact match ..like Attendee field for example.. The user might enter 'John Doe' whereas the table has a attendee column with one of the cells value as 'John Doe - the genius'.. i want to be able to search for the term entered within cell values. How do i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of [*catch-all query*](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/).

---

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[test_fn_transaction_search]    
(
   @receiptnum      VARCHAR(4001) =     NULL,
    @account        VARCHAR(4001) =     NULL,
    @FN             VARCHAR(4001) =     NULL,
    @ln             VARCHAR(4001) =     NULL,
    @dt             VARCHAR(4001) =     NULL,
    @program        VARCHAR(4001) =     NULL,
    @attendee       VARCHAR(4001) =     NULL
)
RETURNS @resulttable TABLE
(
    trid            INT,
    trdate          VARCHAR(4001),
    tramount        MONEY,
    trinvoice       VARCHAR(4001),
    trcashierid     VARCHAR(4001),
    trvoided        VARCHAR(4001),
    trrecallid      VARCHAR(4001),
    trrecalltype    VARCHAR(4001),
    trattendee      VARCHAR(4001),
    trperiod        VARCHAR(4001),
    stopbilling     VARCHAR(4001),
    caccount        VARCHAR(4001),
    firstname       VARCHAR(4001),
    lastname        VARCHAR(4001),
    trprogram       VARCHAR(4001),
    itemlookupcode  VARCHAR(4001),
    paydate         VARCHAR(4001)
)
AS
BEGIN  
    
    INSERT INTO @resulttable
        SELECT 
            tr.ID AS [Transaction ID],
            tr.Time AS [trDt],
            tr.Total AS [amount], 
            tr.ReceiptNumber AS [invoice],
            tr.CashierID AS [cashid], 
            tr.Voided AS [voided],
            tr.RecallID AS [recallid],
            tr.RecallType AS [recalltype], 
            tr.Comment AS [attendee],
            tr.ReferenceNumber AS [trperiod],
            tr.StopBilling  AS [stopbilling],            
            c.AccountNumber AS [accountnum],
            c.FirstName AS [firstname],
            c.LastName AS [lastname],
            it.Description AS [programname],
            it.ItemLookupCode AS [trItemLookupCode],
            tent.PaymentDate AS [paydate]
     FROM [Transaction] tr
     INNER JOIN TransactionEntry trent
        ON trent.TransactionID = tr.ID
     INNER JOIN Item it
        ON trent.ItemID = it.ID
     INNER JOIN Customer c
        ON c.ID=tr.CustomerID
     INNER JOIN TenderEntry tent
        ON tent.TransactionID = tr.ID
     WHERE
        tr.RecallID = 0
        AND (tr.ReceiptNumber = @receiptnum OR @receiptnum IS NULL)
        AND (c.accountnumber = @account OR @account IS NULL)
        AND (c.FirstName = @FN OR @FN IS NULL)
        AND (c.LastName = @ln OR @ln IS NULL)
        AND (tr.time = @dt OR @dt IS NULL) 
        AND (tr.Comment LIKE @attendee + '%' OR @attendee IS NULL)

RETURN
END
```

---

Notes:

1. Try passing `NULL` instead of `''` for fields without values.
2. [Stop using the old-style JOIN](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)
3. Maybe it should be an ITVF rather than MTVF.

Comment: Why do you suggest using a stored procedure instead of a function? I am not doing any dta modification so a function should suffice right?

Comment: It should be enough. Anyway, ignore my UDF to SP suggestion as I'm not really sure what suits best. But I suggest you turn this into ITVF. Read this for more info:  http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/archive/2012/02/comparing-inline-and-multistatement-table-valued-functions/

Comment: This function dosent return me any results.